# Explain what happens if you use KKT to solve this problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, karush-kuhn-tucker

Explain what happens if you use KKT to solve this problem:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
& \underset{(x,y)\epsilon \mathbb{R}^2}{\text{minimize}}
& & x+y \\
& \text{subject to}
& & x^2-y+1 \leqslant 0 \\ &&& y-2x \leqslant 0
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

EDIT: The only issue I had was when I tried to solve this and got y=2x for for slack variables = (0,1/2) and (x,y) = (-1/2,1) for slack variables = (1,0). And since this is a convex program, it should have a single minimum point.

Comment: By the way, those two conditions only intersect at a single point $(1,2)$, so there's only a single allowed value $x+y=3$, which is by default the minimum.

Comment: Also, would you kindly explain what is KKT (I'm not familiar with the term)

Comment: KKT stands for Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

Comment: Yukti Kathuria, thank you